# How do i find regasm.exe in the installer of my program?

Tags: .net, regasm

My program uses registered by regasm.exe .net classes. 
On my computer *regasm.exe* located at *C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319* folder, but on another computer it maybe located at ...\v4.0.1234 or even ...\v4.2.1234.

How do I know where is it located, so i could create an installer for my program?

Comment: Assuming you are making API calls, can't you just include the binary in your project?  Is there anything keeping you from doing that?

Comment: The installer already knows how to register the assembly, it doesn't need regasm.exe.  Use the Register property.